# Не получается составить программу для решения задачи на нахождение суммы четных чисел от 17 до 28

Tags: basic

```
Sub Main
    S=0
    For i=17 to 28 step 1
        if Imod2=0 then
        S=S+i
        Next
    Elseif Imod2<>0 then
        i
      MsgBox ("вывод S="& i)
    End if
End Sub
```

Comment: Наверное, кто-то скопировал искажённое `Imod2`, не подумав, что это значит

Comment: Увы, далёк от тематики программирования. Но и юристам порой такие задания дают.

Comment: То, что я выделил, погуглите.  И Elseif секция не нужна.

Comment: Спасибо Вам. А то набросились тут, когда просто за помощью обратился.

Comment: И MsgBox слегка не там, где надо. PS. *А то набросились тут, когда просто за помощью обратился.* Вам в пять голосов объяснили, почему. Но обижаться, конечно, проще...

Comment: Обид нет никаких. Но ведь если у Вас что-то болит, Вы, вероятнее всего, пойдёте к нужному врачу, который вряд ли Вам предъявит за отсутствие знаний в медицинской сфере и трату его драгоценного времени. Спасибо Вам за помощь!

Comment: @ДмитрийГолубев, плохой аргумент. И давайте не будем тут философствовать по поводу докторов, здесь не мэйл, и даже не тостер.

Comment: @0-LevelUNIXMonk Извините. Святую святых больше не трону.

Comment: Премного благодарю каждого отозвавшегося! Впредь надеюсь если и обращаться за помощью здесь, то с более серьёзными задачами. В технических науках я, к сожалению, не силён, извините.

Answer (score 1):

Должно получиться что-то подобное:

```
Sub Main
    S=0
    For i = 17 to 28
        if I mod 2=0 then
         S=S+i
        End if
    Next
    MsgBox ("вывод S
End Sub
```